# Можно ли инициализировать константу класса enum вне класса?

Tags: c++

Есть enum:

```
enum :int {OneCop , FiveCops, TenCops, FivtyCops, One, Two, Five, Ten, Fivty, Hundred, FiveHundereds, Tousand, FiveTousand};
```

Можно ли инициализировать переменные вне "enum", те как-то так:

```
enum :int {OneCop , FiveCops, TenCops, FivtyCops, One, Two, Five, Ten, Fivty, Hundred, FiveHundereds, Tousand, FiveTousand};
   OneCop = 0;
```

У меня при попытке подобного пишет: "expression must be a modificated lmalue"

Comment: Ну как вы будете менять **константу**?... Нет, нельзя.

Comment: Дамм... Затупил. Спасибо

Comment: по умолчанию записывается в int,  указание  :int  лишняя запись...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут имеется фундаментальное непонимание енумераторов. Идентификаторы, перечисляемые внутри енумераторов, не являются полями, как в структурах или классах. Они существуют только во время компиляции и не присутствуют в памяти программы, нельзя получить их адрес или ссылаться на них. При их использовании получается выражение категории prvalue, аналогично встроенным литералам. И значение для них должно идти сразу и являться константным выражением.

```
enum Cops:int {OneCop = 0, FiveCops = 1,
```

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. Весь смысл enum-а это мапнуть константный числовой массив в какие-то человекочитаемые названия.

И ещё лучше использовать `enum class`